# What is the Schein rank of the Boolean matrix given below?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I am reading: Boolean Matrix Theory by K.H. Kim.  On page 37 the definition for Schein rank is given.

> **Def 1.4.1**: For vectors $v,w$ the symbol $c(v,w)$ will denote the matrix $(v_i w_j)$.  Such matrices are called *cross-vectors*.

> **Def 1.4.2**:  The *Schein rank* of a matrix $A$ is the least number of cross-vectors whose sum is $A$.

Example 1.4.1   $A = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

The text states the Schein rank of $A$ is $3$.

Why is the Schein rank equal to $3$?  What $3 $ cross-vectors sum to $A$.

Comment: I don't think this is true, since the actual rank of A is four. If I am not crazy right now then the rank is always less or equal to the schein rank.

Comment: I understand why the row rank and column rank of A are both equal to 4.   A theorem in the text says that the Schein rank is at most the minimum of the row rank and column rank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cross-vector is a Boolean matrix which is a result of product of two Boolean vectors.

Example: for $v = (1,1,0,0), w = (0,1,1,0)$ we have
$$
c(v,w) = 
 \left(
\begin{matrix}
1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{matrix}\right)
\circ
 \left(
\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{matrix}
\right) = 
 \left(
\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}
\right).
$$

The matrix has Schein rank 3 because it is
$$
A = 
 \left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}
\right)
\vee
 \left(
\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}
\right) \vee
 \left(
\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right).
$$